# Why was this question closed as offtopic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic, reopen-closed

Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448887/mesoshadoopspark-how-to-correctly-setup

If we look at FAQ [definition of ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), this question belongs to at least two of fours:

> - a specific programming problem  (MAYBE)
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers  (YES)
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession (YES)

I think that this could be a *too localized* but anyways, we could give that question a chance, as it possibly could help future visitors.

Comment: Closed by casperOne which means it must be an incorrect close, amiright? High fives all around!

Comment: It is closed as off topic, but it looks like a "too localized" to me. Somebody's made a mess out of their system, and wants help un-messing. The right answer is almost certainly to blow everything away and try again.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I took that as sarcasm aimed at the OP's "not the first time for casperOne" comment. You sure it's not inter-moderator play?

Comment: I don't really think so, @Dave, but I could be wrong. And I don't *think* the OP's a mod anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I thought you were referring to random's comment--obviously the OP isn't a mod...

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was talking about a comment in the original rev of the question. Random's comment is just random. He earned that name.

Comment: For the record: the original revision of this question contained the following sentence: `P.S. That is not the first time, when @CasperOne closes the question that shouldn't be closed IMO.` that's what random's comment is referring to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's all the fuss about?

This question is six months old.  In that time, it has not attracted a single answer.  It's the very definition of too localized.  Now, because of this meta question, it has attracted four reopen votes.

Seriously?

Comment: As of right now, it only needs one more delete vote though!

Comment: To be fair, it also was closed for 4 of those months. That's still two months open without an answer, but it's only 2, not 6.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If someone is really interested in posting an answer, they can always flag to reopen.  I generally oblige if they can actually answer the question.